# Nodejs - imagemagick SIGKILL error when converting pdf to images

Tags: imagemagick

I'm running on Node 16, with `imagemagick 0.1.3`, on several PDFs the conversion fails on SIGKILL error:

```
Error: Command failed: 
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/imagemagick/imagemagick.js:88:15)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
at Process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:14)
```

I tried converting just a single page of the PDFs, or using `png` format instead of `jpg`, but I still get the same error.

Please advise how can I attempt to resolve this?

Comment: Does the conversion work on any PDFs at all? If so, are the ones that fail bigger than the others? Or do they take longer?

Comment: Others work fine, there's no size correlation between the PDFs that pass or fail. And time to failure is quite short.

Comment: One idea would be to try the conversion *"stand-alone"* outside of `node.js` in a Terminal and see if it is `node.js` that is *"unhappy"* or **ImageMagick** and it gives you better error messages. Basic command would be `magick INPUT.PDF OUTPUT.JPG`

Comment: If that works, I'd guess it is the `node` binding and you can maybe work around it by spawning a subprocess from `node` using something like `system()`.